# Deleting Multiple documents in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

Is there a way in the python couchbase client (or any client) to delete a list of documents by ID? I know I can create a loop and delete them one by one, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it with one call.

Comment: Which programming language/Couchbase SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recent libcouchbase-based python client has function delete_multi this is the unit test which demonstrate how to use it https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/tests/test_delete.py

Comment: Thanks, just upgraded to v1 of the python client. Was on .0.82